# Does Localhost perform better on windows?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking

I have a .NET 3.5 server application that usually has about 8 clients.  I'm using `System.Net.Sockets` for all the networking.

I've been told that if a client is running on the same box, it should use `localhost:<port>` or `127.0.0.1:<port>` instead of the machine's ip or name for better performance.  Several people at work have said that this skips some layers of the tcp stack.

But I'm not able to see any performance difference at all in testing (timing how long it takes to get a ping packet from server to client using System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch).

Should there really be better performance in theory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of local domain vs localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037368/performance-of-local-domain-vs-localhost)

Comment: You're right.  I searched first, and I didn't find that.  Stackoverflow is rejecting my attempts to delete because of "too many existing answers."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, performance is same in both cases. If you are using your local device ip address, your operating system kernel don't transport your packets data to your network device and this data don't be was sended anywhere then you don't have any ISO layers calculations (encapsulation, decapsulation etc).

I belive the OS will see this is a local device and you treat it like it was `127.0.0.1`. So in fact both will have the same effect.

Comment: Add to this reply, i belive the OS will see this is a local device and you treat it like it was 127.0.0.1. So in fact both will have the same effect

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's possible that there will be an *extremely* tiny performance boost in using 127.0.0.1 (though I doubt it), but with 8 clients you'll never notice it.  That performance difference would have to be aggregate over A LOT of traffic to become at all noticeable.

The larger concern would be which value is better from a maintenance perspective.  If the application is always looking at localhost for external dependencies, it won't do well if run on another host.  But if it's looking for a more universally understood address for those dependencies, it'll find them from anywhere on the network.